# Why were the three error log files created?

Tags: android

I use the following code to catch a global uncaught error, the test code `System.out.println(s.equals("any string"));` will cause an error.

In my mind, one error log file will be created, but in fact, the three error log files were created with same content, what problem are there in my code?

BTW, I test the code in Android 4.0, only one error log file was generated! but when it run under Android 5.0, three error log files was generated!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println(s.equals("any string"));
    }

}
```

**CrashApplication.java**

```
public class CrashApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        CrashHandler crashHandler = CrashHandler.getInstance();
        crashHandler.init(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

**CrashHandler.java**

```
public class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public static final String TAG = "CrashHandler";   
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultHandler;  
    private static CrashHandler INSTANCE = new CrashHandler();   
    private Context mContext;

    private Map<String, String> infos = new HashMap<String, String>();


    private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");


    private CrashHandler() {
    }


    public static synchronized  CrashHandler getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    public void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;      
        mDefaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();       
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        if (!handleException(ex) && mDefaultHandler != null) {

            mDefaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error : ", e);
            }

            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    private boolean handleException(Throwable ex) {
        if (ex == null) {
            return false;
        }

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sorry.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();

        collectDeviceInfo(mContext);

        saveCrashInfo2File(ex);
        return true;
    }

    public void collectDeviceInfo(Context ctx) {
        try {
            PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            if (pi != null) {
                String versionName = pi.versionName == null ? "null" : pi.versionName;
                String versionCode = pi.versionCode + "";
                infos.put("versionName", versionName);
                infos.put("versionCode", versionCode);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "an error occured when collect package info", e);
        }
        Field[] fields = Build.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                infos.put(field.getName(), field.get(null).toString());
                Log.d(TAG, field.getName() + " : " + field.get(null));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "an error occured when collect crash info", e);
            }
        }
    }


    private String saveCrashInfo2File(Throwable ex) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : infos.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            sb.append(key + "=" + value + "\n");
        }

        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
        ex.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        while (cause != null) {
            cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            cause = cause.getCause();
        }
        printWriter.close();
        String result = writer.toString();
        sb.append(result);
        try {
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String time = formatter.format(new Date());
            String fileName = "crash-" + time + "-" + timestamp + ".txt";
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyCrash/";
                File dir = new File(path);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName);
                fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
            return fileName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "an error occured while writing file...", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try logging the exception type and message  for each log file. There could be 3 different exceptions that are getting logged.

Comment: Also add some print statements to distinguish  how many times handleException gets called and how many times uncaughtException() gets called. This will help you find if the logs are caused by issue with the handler code or because activity/application .

Comment: Thanks! But Android 4.0 only generate one error log file.  Why?

Comment: Yes because there were some changes wrt Activity handling in 5.0. So having the exception cause would help understand the cause

Comment: Did you try and log the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

There are different log files in android:  Error,Debug,Verbose etc.
And therefore there are different qualifiers for them and they are Log.e,Log.d,Log.v etc. Two of them you are using e and d qualifiers but I don't know about third

Comment: Thanks! I mean my customize error log file, String fileName = "crash-" + time + "-" + timestamp + ".txt";  I write uncaught error to my customize log file!